# I am trying to get clild blog menus into parent

Tags: wordpress

first i did create child blog from the network and on success displayed menus on pop window you can check this link " http://prntscr.com/anvweq " but on pop up window i am getting parent page menus not child blog menus

```
function count_menu() {
$target_blog_id         = $this->cloner->target_id;
//exit;
switch_to_blog($target_blog_id);
global $menu;
$menu_num = 0;
$parItems = $menu; 
$count_menu = array();
foreach ($parItems as $k => $menuItem) {
$menu_num++;
if(!empty($menuItem[0])) {

$menu_slug = $menuItem[2];
$get_menu_name = explode("<span", $menuItem[0]);
$menu_name = (empty($get_menu_name[0])) ? $menu_slug : $get_menu_name[0];
$wps_clean_name = $this->wps_clean_name($get_menu_name[0]);

$count_menu[] =   '<input type="hidden" name="parentmenu_item['.$menu_num.']" value="'.$wps_clean_name.'^' . $menu_slug . '^' . $menu_num . '" /><input type="checkbox" class="widefat edit-menu-item-title" name="menu_item_hide['.$menu_num.']" id="menu_item_hide['.$menu_num.']" value="hide" /><label for="menu_item_hide['.$menu_num.']"><strong>'.$menu_name.'</strong></label>';
}
}
restore_current_blog();
return $count_menu;
}
```

Comment: `$menu` is the prepopulated variable from the main blog. It will not be modified if you switch blogs. Get the menu items from the child blog with [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) after you switched blogs.

Comment: i uses this switch_to_blog( $target_blog_id  );
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

   // get primary nav of parent blog
   if ( isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) )
   {
     $menu       = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
     $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id);
   }in this function menu pass but i am not getting what will be menu name